# Помогите пожалуйста осуществить "быстрый старт" с libvpx на C++ (для создания WebM видео)

Tags: c++, видео

Собрал libvpx.a с хидерами под MinGW, нужно клеить WebM видео из кадров с веб-камер. Камеры снимают в YUY2, есть алгоритм конвертации в RGB.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно для создания WebM-файла, какой порядок действий?

Comment: Первое вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491649/how-to-convert-yuy2-to-a-bitmap-in-c

Comment: @nick_n_a, )) нет, "есть алгоритм конвертации в RGB" это не вопрос, это то, что уже есть. Мне бы понять как работать с WebM и его кодеками VP8/VP9 с использованием libvpx.

Comment: Без опыта в кодеках, я бы вам посоветовал http://www.adobe.com/devnet/f4v.html всётаки flv с методом сжатия jpg (страница 8). flv тоже поддерживается в браузерах.

Comment: Конкретно по webm мне кажется лучше копать тут https://github.com/webmproject/libwebm

Comment: Да копаю конечно, но там сырое описание функций и структур, без конкретных примеров. Без понимания базовых принципов и требований сложно в этом всём разобраться. Кстати, .flv не вариант, так как его андроид-браузеры не "едят"